# How to reinstall system python 2.7 on Linux Mint 18.3 WITHOUT reinstalling the OS?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, python, pip

On a clean install of Linux Mint 18.3 I ran the following commands through the terminal:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
pip install install --upgrade pip
pip install future
pip install six
```

Now when I run `pip install <package name>` or `sudo pip install <package name>` neither works. Generally I'll get an error message that looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

I think it was the `pip install install --upgrade pip` command that broke everything but yeah this was a terrible idea and I've given up on what I was trying to. All I want now it to return my system python to it's factory setting without having to completely reinstall Linux Mint. Is that possible?

Comment: This is one of my annoyances with the new pip 10 release. The packages you are using expect pip <= 9.

Comment: @EdwardMinnix yes it sucks. The  python devs seem like they are aggressively trying to kill python 2.7. it's a just cause but sometimes I disagree with their methods.

Comment: This is not a Python 2 versus Python 3 issue, this is a pip issue (anything from 2.7 to 3.6).

Comment: In fact, it's an Ubuntu issue, because packages installed with `apt` are protected against overwriting. So when you issue `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`, you actually don't update anything - you install another copy of `pip` in `/usr/local/`. The error is because `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages` precedes `/usr/lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages`, so `pip==8.1.2` from `python-pip` tries to use incompatible code from `pip==10.0.0`, thus causing the import error. An easy fix is to place `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`, so the correct executable is used when calling `pip`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're issue is being on too-modern a version of pip (10+), you can always revert it to the previous version (e.g., pip 9.0.3 which was the last version prior to pip 10). You can do this from the command line:

```
pip install pip==9.0.3
```

Comment: on my broken python this 
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I am on a virtualbox linuxmint 18 Sarah installation.
I got into a real mess when I tried to update pip.
*(eventually a missing frozen keyword when using the new pip for installations)*

After trying to follow the various instructions like the one above, I did a brute force reinstall until I could run my python tests again and continue development.

Here it goes:

- First the system upgrade (apt update && apt upgrade)
- then remove all python installations brute force 
  (uninstalling python2.7 with the package manager will leave many
  broken packages behind)

  ```
  rm -f /usr/bin/pip*
  rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7

  rm -f /usr/local/bin/pip*
  rm -f /usr/local/bin/pyt*
  rm -f /usr/local/bin/pip*
  rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7

  rm -rf $HOME/.local/bin/pyt*
  rm -rf $HOME/.local/bin/pip*
  rm -rf $HOME/.local/lib/python2.7
  ```
- reinstall python from linux packages giving a working pip

  ```
  apt install python2.7  --reinstall
  apt install python-pip --reinstall
  apt install python-setuptools --reinstall
  apt install python-pkg-resources  --reinstall
  ```
- reinstall needed python package from using pip, e.g.:

  ```
  pip install wheel
  pip install grequests        
  pip install pytest
  pip install flask
  pip install chardet
  pip install prometheus_client
  pip install bs4
  ```

The python packages you need to reinstall might vary obviously for your setup.
I hope I didn't miss anything important from my command history, but you should get the general idea. The longest was the system upgrade. Everything else wen quite quick